# How to click on link on webpage when it is opened through mac-terminal?

Tags: macos

I am using open command in my Mac terminal to launch a website through default browser which is Mozilla firefox , Now how to click on a link given in webpage

Answer (score 2):

For automatically clicking, consider Selenium IDE:

http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/

(Selenium is unrelated to the mac open command, which by the way has a --args option.   But how you would tell firefox to click on a link by passing it some command-line arguments is not clear to me.)